# Increment page value when passing through URL

Tags: php, parameter-passing, post-increment

I need to pass the value of page by increasing one. This is my pure code

```
<?php echo "<li><a href='pro.php?page=$page'><span class='ico-next'></span></a></li>" ?>
```

this is I tried one

```
<?php echo "<li><a href='pro.php?page=.$page++.'><span class='ico-next'></span></a></li>" ?>
```

But its not working,how can I pass the value by increasing it by one

Comment: $page =  $page++; or ++$page

Comment: Where do you read your GET/POST variable? $_GET

Comment: `<a href='pro.php?page=".(++$page).">`

Comment: your second attempt is *almost* correct, you simply need to end the string so you concatenate onto it, rather than *within* it, `?page=".$page++."'>` (note the quotes added to close/open the string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible due to limitations of the php parser. You have to use concatenation instead:

```
<?php echo "<li><a href='pro.php?page=" . ++$page . "'>";
```

Some find it easier to read such style, it separates formatting and computation:

```
<?php echo sprintf("<li><a href='pro.php?page=%s'>", ++$page);
```

Note that you *probably* also need to use `++$page` instead of `$page++`, though that depends on your actual situation.

Comment: Thank u very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You first need to increment the variable before you print it to the page.

```
<?php echo "<li><a href='pro.php?page=".trim(++$page)."'><span class='ico-next'></span></a></li>" ?>
```